# Prove $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for $n = 0, 1, ... , k-1$

Tags: induction

It's a homework problem.  Prove $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ for $n = 0, 1, ... , k-1$

I think induction needs to be used, I can do $n = 0$ (and $n = 1$ since our teacher likes us to do the first two), but $n = m$ confuses me...  Do you have to limit it so $m < k-1$ or something?

Sorry that's a brief explanation...

**Edit:**  $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{1*2*...*k}$, also $\binom{n}{0} = 1$

I think what I am trying to ask is how do I approach this problem?  You can prove the base case very easily, but I am not sure what the inductive hypothesis would be exactly, because $n$ is not $0,1,...,\infty$, but rather $0,1,...,k-1$  A hint on that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is your definition of $(-1)!$?

Comment: More to the point, what is your definition of ${n\choose k}$?

Comment: This is a weird question because usually it's *defined* to be $0$ when $n<k$, so you need to be explicit about your definition.

Comment: Hopefully the edit makes a little more sense.

Comment: Could you give us what $n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)$ is supposed to mean when $n<k$? How many times are we multiplying?

Comment: With the definition provided, do you even need induction? Your definition says that $\binom{n}{k}$ is proportional to $(n-l)$ for $l=0,1,\dots, k-1$, so for $0\leq n \leq k-1$, $\binom{n}{k}=0$.

Comment: If you take the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ as being "the number of ways to select $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects", then you can just make the argument that one cannot select more objects than the total number available. Some might consider that being cheeky, however.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but I'm curious. It seems to me that having $\binom{n}{0}=1$ as part of the definition without saying anything about $n = 0$ or $n < k$ is a bit disingenuous. How do you prove $\binom{0}{k} = 0$? Because there's an $n$ up there? Then how about $\binom{0}{0}$?

Comment: For $n<k$, we still have 

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!}$$which is obviously $0$ by inspection.

Comment: @avid19 $$n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)=\left(n\right)_k$$, where $\left(n\right)_k$ is the falling pocchammer symbol.

Comment: I think you can limit it to where $k > n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, otherwise $\binom{n}{k} = 1$.